# Flutter FutureBuilder not continuing / working

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In my code you can see I am trying to return a List for a ListView. The FutureBuilder should check if it is connected and then add the Items into the list, but it does not seem to work. As I debug I wrote `print("starting") and print("startingfuture")` but I only get the first one outputted so I think the code is not continuing after FutureBuilder(...

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't get any error that could be because of your function, need to see it's code.

Also could you try below structure and tell me what's printing?

```
if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
            return print("waiting");
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) 
              if (snapshot.hasError) {return ("error");}
            return print("everything is ok")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you can see my code via the link below "hastebin...". I wrote a print after FutureBuilder(... (view code) but did not get a response

Comment: I couldn't see getPlants() function in your code, anyway perhaps your builder waiting the listdata.getPlants(), function has completed but it hasn't somehow but I suspect  `AsyncSnapshot<List<PlantsMainItem>>` part in the code so can you try `AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<PlantsMainItem>>>` instead of it?

Comment: I dont know how but I fixed it anyway, ty